# Printing PCBs using conductive paint?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

Has anyone tried to use a programmable cutting machine like a Silhouette CAMEO to cut a stencil for a circuit and then used conductive paint to transfer it to a board?
Could that work? What kind of paint would that require? How expensive would it be?
I there maybe paint that contains solder particles or something, so that I could properly solder other things to it?

I'm not interested in etching PCBs or any alternatives, I just want to know if that could work and what it's limitations would be.

Comment: Check hackaday.com and hackaday.io. Lots of projects out there using CNC-style carriages and conductive paint.

Comment: This is more commonly called 'direct write': Interesting article http://www.optomec.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Optomec_Aerosol_Jet_Direct_Write_Printing_for_Mil_Aero_Electronic_Apps.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cutting a stencil as you suggest is not a viable option. The main reason is that for almost any circuit there are parts of your stencil that will fall away as you pick it up from the cutting board and try to transfer it to the circuit board medium. The simplest way to describe the problem is to consider a similar application with a font stencil where the parts inside letters like **B**, **D** and **P** will fall out.

Conductive inking is done on some materials like the clear plastic sheets that you will find inside the typical cheap computer keyboard. But the typical applications of such are relatively high impedance circuits with low current flow. The typical conductive inks are also not normally particularly solderable and even if tried will melt or burn the carrier medium.